# Array to string conversion error to replace two elements

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, str-replace

I have this code:

```
<?php
$url_constructor = "http://myecommerce.dev/edit/article_name/article_id";
$cart_line_link = str_replace($url_constructor, array(
    'article_id',
    'article_name'
) , array(
    $line['article_name'],
    $line['article_id']
));
```

I need replace the /article_name and /article_id by the cart lines variables.

I want get a result like this example with article:
"http://myecommerce.dev/edit/blue-mug/1728"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax of [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) is:

```
str_replace ($search, $replace, $subject);
```

So, try this:

```
$cart_line_link = str_replace(array(
    'article_id',
    'article_name'
), array(
    $line['article_name'],
    $line['article_id']
), $url_constructor);
```